# What is the value of href attribute in openid.server link tag if Techorati OpenID is hosted at my site?

Tags: openid

I want to log in to Stack Overflow with Techorati OpenID hosted at my site.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login has some basic information.

I understood that I should change

```
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://yourname.x.com" />
```

to

```
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://technorati.com/people/technorati/USERNAME/" />
```

but if I change

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://x.com/server" />
```

to

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://technorati.com/server" />
```

or

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://technorati.com/" />
```

it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to find out the answer to this question is to load the page you want to delegate to (http://technorati.com/people/technorati/USERNAME in this case), look at the source, and find the server tag used there.

If there are openid2 tags, you should copy those as well.

Answer (score 1):

From http://blog.blogupp.com/2008/06/get-openid-fied-and-discover-new-web.html

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://technorati.com/openid/"
```